# <QuerySet []> is not JSON serializable - Django Session

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to set session but it is giving me error

> is not JSON serializable

```
 self.request.session['acl_permissions'] = AclRoleAccess.objects.filter(
                Q(acl_company=self.request.user.userprofile.user_company) &
                Q(acl_role=self.request.user.userprofile.user_role) &
                Q(acl_has_access=True)
            )

    if 'acl_permissions' in self.request.session:
                acl_permissions = self.request.session['acl_permissions']
                print(acl_permissions)
```

How can i store QuerySet in Session. And what will be right way?

Comment: store the ids in session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are setting queryset to session object which is not serializable, add an `ModelSerializer` and pass `queryset` result to serializer with `many` flag as `True` and set serializer.data to session object.

your code will look something like this

```
query_set = AclRoleAccess.objects.filter(
                acl_company=self.request.user.userprofile.user_company,
                acl_role=self.request.user.userprofile.user_role,
                acl_has_access=True)

serializer = AclRoleAccessSerializer(query_set, many=True)
self.request.session['acl_permissions'] = serializer.data
```

where `AclRoleAccessSerializer` is model serializer for `AclRoleAccess` model

Comment: you don't need `Q object`, if you are only using 'AND' in queries, for more info please see this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: name 'AclRoleAccessSerializer' is not defined

Comment: I advised you to create `AclRoleAccessSerializer` serializer using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)
.
if you are not using DRF then you can iterate through the queryset to get data

`serialized_data = [acl_object.id for acl_object in query_set]`  

`self.request.session['acl_permissions'] = serialized_data`